# How does txm_module_object_allocate((void**)obj_ptr, sizeof(obj)) work?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, rtos, threadx

Whenever I try to create an object(queue, thread, or byte pool) I can only create them by doing dynamic memory allocation; it fails if I try a static memory allocation.

I am unable to find the `txm_module_object_allocate` API anywhere in the documentation.

```
//Works:
TX_BYTE_POOL* my_byte_pool=NULL;
txm_module_object_allocate(&my_byte_pool, sizeof(TX_BYTE_POOL));
tx_byte_pool_create(my_byte_pool, "Task Pool", free_memory_task, 16*1240);

//Fails:
TX_BYTE_POOL my_byte_pool;
tx_byte_pool_create(&my_byte_pool, "Task Pool", free_memory_task, 16*1240);
```

In the second case, I always get the error that `tx_byte_pool_create` failed.

Comment: What is the first argument to `tx_byte_pool_create` supposed to be? In the "working" case you pass something of type `TX_BYTE_POOL*` while in the "failing" case you pass something of type `TX_BYTE_POOL`. Should it be a pointer to `TX_BYTE_POOL` or not? And doesn't the compiler complain when you pass the wrong type?

Comment: I have corrected and shortened both the title and the body text (deleted what was essentially a repetition) of this question, in order to hopefully strengthen its impact.

Comment: `txm_module_object_allocate` or `tx_module_object_allocate`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out it's txm_module_object_allocate.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for pointing out the typo, I have edited the question. Hence, `tx_byte_pool_create` accepts a pointer to `TX_BYTE_POOL`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, txm_module_object_allocate expects the first argument to be a pointer of type TX_BYTE_POOL . So the correct syntax or the function to be called is txm_module_object_allocate(&my_byte_pool, sizeof(TX_BYTE_POOL));